# Gmail email with multi column table layout auto spacing doesn't work

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, email-templates

I am trying to design a email template in plain `html` and `css` to display emails with multi column tabular layout. Below is my markup, its working perfectly well on Microsoft outlook with the right spacing, auto alignment but gmail is not doing well with auto spacing and alignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            color: #505050;
        }
        .danger {
            background-color: red;
            display:inline;
        }
        .warning {
            background-color: orange;
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>    
        <a href="https://myalerts.com">
            <span>Alerts1</span>
        </a>
        <hr />
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">20</td>
        <td>Alpha Clinic</td>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">25</td>
        <td>Bravo Clinic</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="danger">55</td>
        <td>Delta Clinic</td>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">34</td>
        <td>Echo Clinic</td>            
        </tr>
        </table>        
        <br />
        <a href="https://myalerts.com">
            <span>Alerts2</span>
        </a>
        <hr />
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="danger">30</td>
        <td>Alpha Clinic</td>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">18</td>
        <td>Bravo Clinic</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">17</td>
        <td>Delta Clinic</td>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="warning">25</td>
        <td>Echo Clinic</td>
        <td style="width:auto;" class="danger">35</td>
        <td>Foxtrot Clinic</td>
        </tr>       
        </table>
        <br />            
</body>
</html>
```

Gmail layout:

[image: Gmail template Layout]

Microsoft Outlook layout:

[image: Outlook template Layout]

Comment: Tried giving your columns a width in percentage?

Comment: percentage width works, but that doesn't do the job with dynamic column values. Is there a better way to handle auto grow/shrink based on the data ?

Comment: `doesn't do the job with dynamic column values`. Dont give the table a width then. It will shrink and grow based on content. Edit your post above to show what will be the max content and min content so someone can help you.

Comment: not giving a width of 100% to the table is shrinking the whole row almost like no spacing between the columns , tried that already.